# how to configure ISPConfig for mod_python or mod_wsgi?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-python, configuration, wsgi

how to configure ISPConfig for mod_python or mod_wsgi for django like apps deployement?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't asked for a specific version of ISPConfig so I'll assume you are using ISPConfig 3.

I didn't tried that by myself, but I've found here a step-by-step instructions on how to install ispconfig3 + django + mod_wsgi - [Django and mod_wsgi | HowToForge Forums](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=24109)

If somethings goes wrong you could try reply to the mentioned thread or start a new thread there and link to that one.

If you want mod_python you can go with this one:
http://www.howtoforge.com/embedding-python-in-apache2-with-mod_python-debian-ubuntu-fedora-centos-mandriva-opensuse